# Use nnet package for raster image classification

Tags: r, neural-network, classification, raster

I have problem with raster classification by 'nnet' package in R. I can't create a raster with predicted class of cells. There is my code:

```
library(sp)
library(nnet)
library(caret)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

images_list=list.files(path="maps", full.names=TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE) 

rasters_stack <- stack(images_list)   

table = read.csv("points.csv", sep = ",")

indeks <- createDataPartition(table$class, p=2/3, list=FALSE)
training <- table[indeks, ] 
test    <- table[-indeks, ]

model = nnet(factor(class) ~ blue + green + red, data = training, size=2)

predict(rasters_stack, model, type="class", filename="output.img",
         progress="text", overwrite=TRUE)
```

and I get these errors:

```
Error in v * x@data@gain : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In rgdal::putRasterData(x@file@transient, v, band = 1, offset = off) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: In rgdal::putRasterData(x@file@transient, v, band = 1, offset = off) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
3: In rgdal::putRasterData(x@file@transient, v, band = 1, offset = off) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
4: In rgdal::putRasterData(x@file@transient, v, band = 1, offset = off) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
5: In .gd_SetStatistics(object, ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: I'd like to take a try. Could you provide the input data or fake data input?

Comment: data in [here](http://www90.zippyshare.com/v/2bLXroUJ/file.html) as author pointed by email.